# What is the output of below program?

Tags: c, loops

While run this problem when it gets terminate the loop?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
  int n=12,res=1;
  clrscr();
  while(n>3)
  {
    n+=3;
    res*=3;
  }
  printf("%d",n*res);
  getch();
}
```

The above result is 3595. But i don't understand the process of while loop. When it gets terminates its loop?

Comment: Learn [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). and C is not C++.

Comment: Your loop is wrong, `n` is always superior to 3 until it overflows !

Comment: As the program have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) it's invalid and any discussion about it's behavior is moot.

Answer (score 9):

The behaviour of your code is *undefined* as you will eventually overflow a `signed` integral type.

The output, therefore, could be anything.

(In your case, it seems that `n` *wraps around* to a negative number, so the `n > 3` conditional is no longer `true`. But **don't** rely on this behaviour: some architectures will *clamp* `n` for example.)